# jQuery animate to screen using (x)%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am running to a little problem in which I want to space out a div from another div by (x)px.

Currently I have the original div at

```
left: '30%';
```

but I want my second div to be

```
left: '30%' + (width of first div) + (5px of border space);
```

currently I can't get it to work since a percentage can't be added with a px value (I believe).

Just wondering if there was any way around this, that is also easy to understand. Thanks!

Comment: This depends lot of your html code.. can you add it and maybe create fiddle too.

Comment: I might be really wrong, but I'm guessing it's because you can't concatenate an integer with a string.  Also, I don't think you can add pixel values to percentages.  Perhaps try `left: '30%'` and `margin-left: String(width + 5) + 'px'` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can be added. use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/Ck8Lq/)**

```
left: calc(30% + 250px + 5px); /* assuming width of your div is 250px;*/
```

**EDIT:** OP needed animation. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/magnus16/Ck8Lq/2/)**

Comment: Nice CSS only solution, but calc() doesn't have very good cross-browser support. http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: Not that much but I would say it is still pretty good. You can't do much with older browsers these days anyway.

Comment: That's true; I guess it really depends on the audience.  According to analytics on my site about 85% are using chrome and another 10% are using a modern browser (i.e. firefox, mostly), so I usually don't have to worry about catering to IE < 10 users.  I really do wish calc() was widely used because it'd be such a timesaver in so many situations haha

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't know why but I don't even click on questions here which even mentions IE.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this works in css, however I also want to animate the div to that position calculated

Comment: Then add css transition.

Answer (score 0):

if the second div's position is relative to the first one, then you should be able to use the offset of the first div instead of a set percent:

```
$('.div2').offset({
    left: $('.div1').offset().left +  $('.div1').outerWidth() + 5
})
```